# Flutter: Notification listener, how to make onNotification dynamic

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to dart and hence flutter. I am using NotificationListener like this

```
   String x = a; // or could be x=b, x=c, etc, comes as function parameter 
    return NotificationListener(
          onNotification: onNotificationHandler,
          child: new ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
               // other codes comes here
```

Problem,

I want value of `onNotification` to be dynamic on the basis of the value of variable `x`
Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

In Dart, `Function` are first class citizen, it means that a Function can be returned from a method.

You can then create a method which takes `x` as parameter and which returns a function which is a `NotificationListenerCallback`. The returned function is what is called a `Closure` which means that is has access to the variables which are in it's lexical scope (`x` is in this case) even if it is executed outside.

In your example, it can be:

```
    String x = a; // or could be x=b, x=c, etc, comes as function parameter 
    return NotificationListener(
      onNotification: _notificationHandler(x), // The return the appropriate function with x scoped to the function to be used later
      child: new ListView.builder(
      // other codes comes here

def _notificationHandler(String value) => (T notification) {
  // Note that the returned function has access to `value`
  // even if it will be executed elsewhere
  return (value == 'Hey); 
}
```

Comment: gives undefined class `def`.